# Checksum Failed error during checkout - Joomla-virtuemart-payumoney-paymentgateway

Tags: joomla-2.5, virtuemart, apache

Our merchant Id is: 5253813

I am a basic joomla website developer. This site was developed using a template with joomla2 and virtuemart2 versions.
I have also installed the payu plugin provided in payumoney website(Payment gate way). 
The problem is once after checkout I am getting the below error.

> "SORRY! We were unable to process your payment Checksum Failed"

Once after getting redirected from the below mentioned URL:
http://example.com/SiteRoot/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=cart&task=confirm&lang=en

Our Configuration information are as follows:

- PHP Built On:                       Linux just25.justhost.com
- Database Version:                   5.5.42-37.1-log
- Database Collation:                 utf8_general_ci
- PHP Version:                        5.4.43
- Web Server:                         Apache
- WebServer to PHP Interface:         cgi-fcgi
- Joomla! Version:                    Joomla! 2.5.28 Stable [ Ember ]
- Joomla! Platform Version:           Joomla Platform 11.4.0 Stable
- VirtueMart:                         2.6.17

Kindly give me some suggestion to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest contacting the developers of VirtueMart and the payment plugin for this sort of question

Comment: Also sometimes the merchant is able to provide helpful advices about the cause of such issues.

Comment: I have mailed them. they have called me once, but after that no response.